# Download WFS features as shapefile using ArcGIS Server

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-server, wfs, file-formats, getfeature

I've been looking everywhere for a way to output a shapefile in ArcServer. A sample ArcServer WFS GetCapabilities response says all the output is either in GML, KML, or JSON.

[image]

This is is very easy using GeoServer:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/bw/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ws:layer&outputFormat=SHAPE-ZIP&
```

Is there an external library I could install on the server-side that would add SHAPE-ZIP to this list?

I'd like to refrain from writing VB.NET / C#.NET, Python, or ogr2ogr to change between file formats.

Comment: ArcGIS Server supports "zip & ship" capabilities in several different ways, but zipped shapefile is not part of the WFS capabilities.  Which would you prefer, WFS or -shp.zip?

Comment: I guess it's fine if I can grab a shp.zip, I was just thinking about it from a GeoServer perspective

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005700000073000000

Comment: I guess it's not possible... Oh well, not surprised at all.

Comment: It's certainly possible, if you create the service as documented.